# US, estimated taxes - but for first filing?

Tags: united-states, estimated-taxes

Just curious - in the US - say it's the *first* time you are filing taxes.

(I suppose the only two possibilities are either (A) you happened to move from overseas or (B) imagine a highly successful teen idol type who suddenly made a lot of money and previously was just a kid and/or made zero money.)

So in 2017 you made $500,000.

It is 100% 1099 income.

But you have never, ever dealt with the IRS before and it's your first filing.

For concreteness say you were paid evenly spaced throughout the year.

In fact - - do you pay the small penalty for not having paid estimated taxes as you go along?

Or are you sort of "exempt" your first go around?

Comment: But note that you _will_ owe interest for paying later than Apr/17 - even if you filed for an extension.

Comment: @Aganju That'd be April 2018, since earnings were 2017.

Comment: Apr/17 in 2018. the 17 was the day (in 2018, taxes are due on the 17th because of Sunday and a DC Holiday)

Comment: @Aganju: Apr/17 is not the way most people in the US would abbreviate April 17th. It would be assumed that you meant April of 2017.

Comment: You wouldn't have to be a "highly successful teen idol" for this question to be relevant. Just someone whose first real income is not subject to withholding. Like someone graduates high school and starts a small business rather than getting a job working for someone else. Probably relatively rare but surely not unheard of.

Comment: That's ok cos Logan Paul won't be making much $$ this quarter

Comment: @smci - hilarious  :)

Comment: @Fattie I'm *deadly* serious ;-)

Comment: hahahahah  :)  :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  From [1040-ES](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf):

> Exception. 
>   You do not have to pay estimated tax for 2017 if you were a U.S. citizen or resident alien for all of 2016 and you had no tax liability for the full 12-month 2016 tax year. You had no tax liability for 2016 if your total tax was zero or you did not have to file an income tax return.

Comment: you guys know everything !

Comment: This covers case A in the question only if you are a US citizen who was previously living 'overseas' -- which US people generally use to mean in a foreign country, even though Canada, Mexico, and Central and South America are not in fact overseas, and HI, PR, Guam etc are).

Comment: How does it not address case B, someone who did not owe tax last year but owes tax this year?

Answer (score 6):

> **In fact - - do you pay the small penalty for not having paid estimated
> taxes as you go along?**

No, an exception to the penalty for underpayment of estimated taxes is made when no tax liability existed in the prior year.
Instructions for [Form 2210](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i2210.pdf) indicate:

> Exceptions to the Penalty
>  You won't have to pay the penalty or file
> this form if either of the following applies.
>
> - You had no tax liability for 2016, you were a U.S. citizen or resident alien for the entire
>   year (or an estate of a domestic decedent or a domestic trust), and
>   your 2016 tax return was (or would have been had you been required to
>   file) for a full 12 months.
>
> ....

Comment: another fantastic answer on the awesome Money site !